Good UX in modal after submitting
I'm not a UX, just a UI developer and I want to have good UX in our modals. What we need to do for it? User confirms the information by clicking on the submit button in the popup.  We send the response to the API. Do we need to disable the submit button after clicking? Do we need to disable/hide the cancel button (the same question around close icon button in the right corner). Maybe we can read something about it

What usually happens after a primary action takes place in a modal is that the modal window closes and the user receives a toast or other message confirming the success of the action. Is there a reason why your modal stays open?

This is maybe more about what happens before we have success/rejection from the api.

Since the user has to wait for a response from the system, it's considered good practice to disable the button to prevent multiple requests.
You can also opt to show a loading indicator in the button, to inform the user that the system is working and a response can be expected at some point.
For example:


After successfully submitting, you can:

Replace the form with a success message, such as "Your form was submitted successfully." An icon with a checkmark and message can also be used here.
If you have info for users on what they need to expect after submitting, show it to them, such as "We'll review your submission and respond within 24 hours."
You can add the links to other pages (see the attached image).
Or give your users an option to submit another form if needed.

